# What's the character encoding for string representations of URIs in Redland RDF?

Tags: encoding, uri, rdf, utf, redland

Is it safe to assume that strings returned by [`librdf_uri_as_string ()`](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-uri.html#librdf-uri-as-string) use UTF-8 encoding. Or is it perhaps [ISO-Latin](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) (with additional URL encoding)?

I am dealing with URIs in an `librdf_model` that was read with `librdf_parser_parse_file_handle_into_model ()` from a `FILE *`. Would it help if I switch to a `raptor_parser` (and perhaps `raptor_iostream` instead of `FILE *` as well)? The [Raptor](http://librdf.org/raptor/libraptor2.html) documentation specifically mentions UTF-8.

Is `librdf_parser` just a wrapper for `raptor_parser` and the answer is UTF-8 because of that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but this seems like a very specific question about a library that might be better addressed to the developers on an appropriate mailing list.  An answer here would be fine, too;  I just expect that you might have better luck there.

Comment: Thx, but there I've got good answers about that library (also) on SO. There is also an existing tag `Redland`.

Comment: Yes, there's redland-dev@lists.librdf.org and #redland on freenode but Stack Overflow works well for questions and answers, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

librdf if one abstraction level up from Raptor. Basically, librdf is an application-level library that wraps Raptor, Rasqal and RDF storages together. If you're working on librdf level, you should basically be using librdf APIs only, though there are some leaky abstractions here and there.

Generally in the API, when you see strings passed in as `(const) unsigned char *`, it's UTF-8 all the way down. Only some identifiers such as syntax names are passed as `(const) char *` and they are ASCII.

Disclosure/caveat: I am a committer in Redland projects but haven't been actively working on them in recent years. I used to know the internals well but my memory isn't perfect.

To answer the specific questions:

> Is it safe to assume that strings returned by `librdf_uri_as_string ()` use UTF-8 encoding.

Yes.

> Would it help if I switch to a `raptor_parser` (and perhaps `raptor_iostream` instead of `FILE *` as well)?

No, there's practically no difference. Just negligible amount of less wrapper code and a slightly different API.

> Is `librdf_parser` just a wrapper for `raptor_parser` and the answer is UTF-8 because of that?

Yes.

Comment: +1 You certainly know your `Redland` still quote well :)